# E2E testing on multiple/parallel browsers in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

Using Protractor how do I setup/add a parallel browsers for testing.

**example:**  Test suites on not only `chrome`, but also `firefox`?  Also is there a simple way of test for mobile? say ios8 safari or mobile chrome?

### **Question:**

How do I write the exports.config object to support `chrome and firefox` in parallel suite testing?

```
   exports.config = {
      multiCapabilities: [
        {
          'browserName': 'chrome',
          'chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--test-type']
          }
        }
      ]}
    suites: {
        homePageFooter: 'protractor/homePage/footer.spec.js'
      },
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you know how to configure multiple browsers, but you are asking specifically about making it work with `suites`? Thanks.

Comment: For now I have a few suite of tests that I want to run in chrome and firefox in parallel.  Nothing special.  Therefore, I dont know how to configure multiple browser.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Just one note: I haven't personally used `suites` (only `specs`) - I'm not sure if `suites` would work inside `multiCapabilities`. The reason I'm worried about it is that, for example, once I had problems with `exclude` in `multiCapabilities` and it turned out that it was not supported - filed an [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1230) which was later fixed. This is just FYI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Using Protractor how do I setup/add a parallel browsers for testing.

You need to list your browsers in [`multiCapabilities`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/browser-setup#testing-against-multiple-browsers):

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}, {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}]
```

> Also is there a simple way of test for mobile? say ios8 safari or
>   mobile chrome?

One option would be to use `Appium` framework, here are the relevant documentation sections:

- [Setting Up Protractor with Appium - Android/Chrome](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/mobile-setup#setting-up-protractor-with-appium-android-chrome)
- [Setting Up Protractor with Appium - iOS/Safari](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/mobile-setup#setting-up-protractor-with-appium-ios-safari)

Another option would be to use [`Browserstack`](http://www.browserstack.com/) (or [`Sauce Labs`](https://saucelabs.com/)) *as your selenium server*. There is a [huge variety of browsers/platforms](http://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live) to choose from, including different mobile devices.

Here is a sample config from one of our internal projects:

```
'use strict';

var browserstackUser = 'user';
var browserstackKey = 'key';

exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.local': 'true',
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',

            'browserName': 'Chrome',
            'os': 'Windows',
            'os_version': '8',

            specs: [
                '*.spec.js'
            ],
            exclude: [
                'footer.disabledCookies.spec.js',
                'footer.disabledFlash.spec.js'
            ]
        },

        {
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.local': 'true',
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',

            'browserName': 'Internet Explorer',
            'browser_version': '9.0',
            'os': 'Windows',
            'os_version': '7',
            'resolution': '1024x768',

            specs: [
                '*.spec.js'
            ],
            exclude: [
                'footer.disabledCookies.spec.js',
                'footer.disabledFlash.spec.js'
            ]
        }
    ],

    maxSessions: 2,

    // Browserstack's selenium server address
    seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

    framework: 'jasmine',

    allScriptsTimeout: 300000,

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001',

    onPrepare: function () {
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
            var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
            var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new
                jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter("test-results", true, true, prePendStr));
        });
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 3600000
    }
};
```